# How to get multiple rotating background cover with css / Full screen slideshow

Tags: html, css

I want to have multiple background images using HTML and CSS *(as those are the only languages I have learned so far)*.

The best result I got for background cover is from `id="full-bg"`. Now how do I make it to multiple background cover photo at the same time rotating(changing in every lets say 5 sec).

Comment: [here](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/01/02/fullscreen-background-image-slideshow-with-css3/) - or with a TINY bit of jquery (you should learn that soon enough) you could look at [this](http://www.slickmedia.co.uk/news/blog/glenns-blog/full-screen-responsive-background-image-with-css/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/181wzf9w/3/)

This code only uses css and rotates trough the backgrounds you add.

```
body{
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: fixed;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-name: fade-bg;
  animation-delay: 0;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: forward;

}

@keyframes fade-bg {
    0% {
        background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/sRnvs0K.jpg');
    }
    50% {
        background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/sRnvs0K.jpg');
    }
    51% {
        background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/wL4RT1w.jpg');
    }
    100% {
        background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/wL4RT1w.jpg');
    }
}
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a cross-browser solution:

```
body{
        -webkit-animation: change 5s linear infinite;   
        -moz-animation: change 5s linear infinite;  
        -ms-animation: change 5s linear infinite;   
        -o-animation: change 5s linear infinite;    
        animation: change 5s linear infinite;
    }


    @-webkit-keyframes change
    {
        0% { background-image:url('your_first_img.jpeg'); }
        100%   {background-image:url('your_second_img.jpeg'); }
    }

    @-moz-keyframes change
    {
        0% { background-image:url('your_first_img.jpeg'); }
        100%   {background-image:url('your_second_img.jpeg'); }
    }

    @-ms-keyframes change
    {
        0% { background-image:url('your_first_img.jpeg'); }
        100%   {background-image:url('your_second_img.jpeg'); }
    }

    @-o-keyframes change
    {
        0% { background-image:url('your_first_img.jpeg'); }
        100%   {background-image:url('your_second_img.jpeg'); }
    }

    @keyframes change
    {
        0% { background-image:url('your_first_img.jpeg'); }
        100%   {background-image:url('your_second_img.jpeg'); }
    }
```